# Oracle SQL: Creating a Primary Key From Created Field

Tags: sql, oracle, key, primary-key

Say I have the table...

```
Name      Null Type         
--------- ---- ------------ 
BOOK_CODE      VARCHAR2(26) 
AUTHOR_ID      NUMBER(2)    
SEQUENCE       NUMBER(1)
```

It's already been created, how would I go about making `BOOK_CODE` the primary Key? The only way I can find is to delete the field and then replace it, but I would lose all the data I put in it that way.

Any Ideas?

Comment: seemed to work for me.   create table mytable (book_code varchar(26), author_id number(2), sequence number(1));
insert into mytable (book_code, author_id, sequence) values('a', 1, 1);
ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(book_code);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME> ADD CONSTRAINT pk_book_code PRIMARY KEY(book_code);
```

For foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

Comment: How would i do a forieng key? the same way?

Comment: Awesome, and how would I be able to see if my keys were set properly?

Comment: what tool are you using to run the scripts? If you are using SQLPlus, you can try this query: select * from  SYS.USER_CONSTRAINTS. List all constraints that could be seen by the logged user.